# Explanation for the Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question a few days back, and the link below was the solution in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/pnhxxcsw/11/

Later on, I got another answer that did the work of the previous solution in just 2 lines of code instead of 8-9.  Since I'm new to coding, I'm unable to figure out how the new JSFiddle works.  If someone could explain it to me, I would be appreciative.

Here is the code and JSFiddle link from the second solution:

```
var div = $('div').not(':first').hide().end();

$('button').on('click', function()  { div.hide().eq($(this).index()).show() })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pnhxxcsw/13/

Thanks in advance

Comment: first stop should be http://api.jquery.com/ and checkout what each of those methods do

Comment: It really is as simple as that.  jQuery is all about the documentation, the implementation is really simple.

Answer (score 3):

the first line is very straight forward to read, we're getting all the divs, filtering them to get everything that is not the first child of it's parent, and hiding them, in other words, hiding everything except for first children.

the second line, we are adding a click event listener to buttons, and when we click, we show only the element with an index matching the clicked button

one more thing, just like the comments stated, check the jquery docs, that's the place to go in these cases